# no routes to destroy an element of a child association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models

```
Parent
  has_many :children

Child
  belongs_to :parent
```

And I would like to have a clean rails route to destroy children from parent.

```
resources :parents do
  resources :children do
    delete 'destroy'
  end
end
```

but I get an error while calling parent_child_destroy_path

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"ads"}
```

The action nevertheless exists...

Anyone does know how to get such a clean route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by clean rails route? You already have everything you need with nested resources:

```
resources :parents do
  resources :children
end
```

And then call the destroy action like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', parent_child_path(@parent, child), :method => :delete %>
```

With the routes you defined, you should write:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', parent_child_destroy_path(@parent, child), :method => :delete %>
```

which is not cleaner.

Comment: thx, I didn't saw this kind of route with rake routes... But do you know why I got the error with the dirty solution?

Comment: @knotito, how do you exactly call your route in your view?

Comment: in fact as u said the problem was the parameters missing... cheers :)